# EDGE VERSION WON'T WORK with seleniumWebdriver all of a sudden

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

Using selenium webdriver with Edge browser. Worked fine until last night/morning. Errors are:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of MSEdgeDriver only supports MSEdge version 96
```

Current browser version is 98.whatever. It says the application was modified on 2/3 of this year, which I didn't consent to as far as I can remember.

Why did that catch? Did it automatically install an update without letting me know? Why would that be?

In any case, TLDR, how do I fix this?! and which does Selenium dislike: my edgeDriver, or Selenium being out of date? should I REVERT EdgeDriver by finding an older version (how?), or would it be best to update Selenium somehow?

Comment: I believe Edge is based on Chromium now, and that will download/install updates automatically unless you turn it off.  You'll want the major versions of the browser and driver to match.

Comment: @pcalkins how do I reconcile webdriver and MSEdge Drivers, now? Thanks for taking the time to comment !

Comment: Get the 98 version of Edgedriver from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Comment: @pcalkins I DO have that version thats what's destroying my scripts :) they say its supported for 96